# Probability that second chosen ball from bag is white

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A bag contains $n$ balls of unknown colours. The first ball taken from the bag was white. What is the probability of second ball is also white, when we assume, that the number of white balls in bag is equally likely?

I guess the key part here is to make use of Bayes' theorem. My idea was to consider such 'disjoint' events.

$A_1$ when bag contains exactly $1$ white ball.
$A_2$ when bag contains exactly $2$ white ball.
$\dots$
$A_n$ when bag contains exactly $n$ white ball.

But I cannot see what is $B$ here, and this idea lead me to dead end.

I have also made a simple c++ [program](https://pastebin.com/JKGyuFcx), which simulates the situation and produces the answer nearly equal to $2/3$. I know this is somewhat useless, but knowing the answer is helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by 'number of white balls in bag is equally likely'?

Comment: Do you replace the first white ball or not before the second draw?

Comment: @B. Mehta. It is equally probable (I'm not sure if this is the correct word) that the bag contains $1$ or $2$ or all the way up to $n$ white balls. The bag should contain at least one white ball.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, no we don't replace.

Comment: @shcolf It is still not clear what you mean by 'equally likely' ... do  all of $A_1$ through $A_n$ have a probability of $\frac{1}{n}$? ... or did you initially have anywhere from $0$ to $n$ balls, each of which having a chance of $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: Well, when the problem said that "The first ball taken from the bag was white.".
That's why I assumed the chance of having $i$ white balls is $\frac{1}{n}$. But now I understand from @Ross Millikan's answer why this is wrong. Should be $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: It actually doesn't matter whether you use $\frac 1n$ for numbers of white balls from $1$ to $n$ as your prior distribution or $\frac 1{n+1}$ for numbers from $0$ to $n$.  The first draw rules out $0$.  My whole answer goes through just the same.  Note that I sum $\frac in$, not $\frac i{n+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your prior distribution is that there is $\frac 1{n+1}$ chance of each number of white balls from $0$ to $n$.  The drawing of a white ball says the probability of $A_0$ is zero.  The chance of $A_i$ is now proportional to $i$ as you had $\frac in$ chance of drawing a white ball if you started with $i$ of them.  The sum of $\frac in$ is $\frac {n(n+1)}{2n}=\frac {n+1}2$ so the probability of $A_i$ is now $\frac {2i}{n(n+1)}$  The chance we get a white ball assuming we started with $i$ white balls is $\frac {i-1}{n-1}$ so the chance we get a white ball overall is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {2i}{n(n+1)}\cdot\frac {i-1}{n-1}=\frac 1{n(n^2-1)}\sum_{i=1}^n(2i^2-2i)\\=\frac 2{n(n^2-1)}\left(\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6-\frac {n(n+1)}2\right)\\=\frac 2{n(n^2-1)}\cdot\frac {n(n+1)(2n-2)}6\\=\frac 23$$